# What is the length of this segment given the radius?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Consider a circumference centered in the origin and with radius $r$. Let $C$ be a point on the circumference, and let $A,B$ be its projections on the axes, respectively $x$-axis and $y$-axis. What is the length of $AB$?

I tried applying the laws of sines and cosines on $ABC$, but I only got tautologies....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture.  Connect $C$ to $A$ and $B$, then connect $A$ and $B$ to the origin.  What shape to you make?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then can't we say $OC = AB$?

Answer (score 1):

You get $A = (r\cos \theta,0)$ and $B = (0,r\sin \theta)$ for some angle $\theta$. Then, using Euclidean distance, the length of the segment $AB$ is given by 
$$ \sqrt{(r\cos \theta-0)^2+(0-r\sin \theta)^2} = \sqrt{r^2} = r.$$